# How to add checkboxes to JTABLE swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

Does anyone know how to put a `JCheckBox` in a `JTable` column? Something like this:

[image: Table from the table tutorial]

I took this from [How To use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: the Swing tutorials tell you exactly how to do such a thing. I recommend you have a look.

Comment: You can get the "checkboxes" column after table creation, and then `setCellEditor( layersTable.getDefaultEditor( Boolean.class ) )` and cell renderer similar way.

PS. I regret this is closed and I can't answer, it's perfect question for quick answer :(

Answer (score 50):

1) [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) knows [JCheckbox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox) with built-in Boolean [TableCellRenderers and TableCellEditor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) by default, then there is contraproductive declare something about that,

2) [AbstractTableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) should be useful, where is in the `JTable` required to reduce/restrict/change nested and inherits methods by default implemented in the `DefaultTableModel`,

3) consider using `DefaultTableModel`, (if you are not sure about how to works) instead of `AbstractTableModel`,

[image: table_with_BooleanType_column]

could be generated from simple code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableCheckBox extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable table;

    public TableCheckBox() {
        Object[] columnNames = {"Type", "Company", "Shares", "Price", "Boolean"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50), false},
            {"Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25), true},
            {"Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35), true},
            {"Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00), false}
        };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            /*@Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }*/
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                    case 0:
                        return String.class;
                    case 1:
                        return String.class;
                    case 2:
                        return Integer.class;
                    case 3:
                        return Double.class;
                    default:
                        return Boolean.class;
                }
            }
        };
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableCheckBox frame = new TableCheckBox();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocation(150, 150);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for subclassing the table for data-related reasons: it's clearly the responsibility of the _model_ to return the correct classes, the view _must not_ second guess that

Comment: 1) I never heard about subClassing issues, seriously do not understand, it might be appropriate to clarify the impetus with posting here a bright example, or link to with detailed subscription, 2) maybe there deepest reasin for why I block non-subclassing code just and only about swift level for OP , 3) imaging that, :-)

Comment: The default `JTable#getColumnClass` method does this: `return getModel().getColumnClass(convertColumnIndexToModel(column));`.  If a user moves the table column, this "solution" will break.  `TableModel#getColumnClass` is what should be overridden.

Comment: Your code has been shamelessly copied [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25533492/522444). I have flagged the moderators regarding that poster's actions.