# Set The Data Type Of Column in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I created a JTable with a table model . Now based on an input which i have, i want to make one column into a particular data Type. How do i do this?

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class MyTableModelTwo extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Object[][] data;
    private String[] columnNames;

    public MyTableModelTwo(Object[][] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndes, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int index) {
        return columnNames[index];
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        data[rowIndex][columnIndex] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }

    public MyTableModelTwo(String[] columnNames, Object[][] data) {
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class MyTableTwo extends JPanel implements TableModelListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable table;
    private Object[][] data;
    private JTextField t;

    public MyTableTwo(int noElements, String[] columnNames) {
        data = new Object[noElements][columnNames.length];
        t = new JTextField();
        MyTableModelTwo m = new MyTableModelTwo(columnNames, data);
        table = new JTable(m);
        table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    }

    public JTextField returnT6() {
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change column type dynamically?

Comment: yes. I have a string which says the column should store only integers. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html. Here he has set the column data as boolean in the data itself. I want too do it dynamically

Comment: what do you mean by "make"? Your implementation returns the class of the content, so fill the column with ints and be happy :-)

Comment: actually, I think it's a misunderstanding about the meaning of "dynamically" - don't think you want to _change_ the type during the life-time of the model, that would be extremely unusual and most probably start the design alarm bell ringing :-)

Comment: i am sorry i was not clear. it need not be integer type only. whatever data i get, i change it to that type.

Comment: @Kaushik Balasubramanain if you'll change that to the DefaultTableModel, then all dynamic changes returns `return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();` no another definitions required, be sure with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

overide [public Class getColumnClass(int column) {...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391877/how-to-add-checkboxes-to-jtable-swing/7392163#comment-8966078)

please my question, why do you needed there AbstractModel, for why reasons, really what do you want to restict/mofify/change/override, ( `you can prety ignore this == be sure that not really not good way to start to playing with anything for JTable based on AbstractTableModel` ), however ... consider using DefalutTableModel rather than AbstractTableModel

Comment: i have overridden it. In the example shown, while making the data itself, the type was specified. The data is already made. Can i Change it now? No column has a specific data type defined as yet

Comment: 1) for Java6 is in most cases required for correctly usage of overide anotations see edit your post 2) `Can i Change it now?` yes

Answer (score 0):

Note:
Columns DO have data types. Run this after you have added at least 1 row.

```
System.out.println("Column Types : "    + table.getColumnClass(0) + "  "                                                                                + table.getColumnClass(1) + "  "                                                         + table.getColumnClass(2)  );
```

The Column Class is important when Sort is used:
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

If a column class is String, but contains numbers, they sort alphabetically and not numerically.
If you put mixed data types into a column (say Strings and integers) and attempt to sort, the sort fails and you get a lot of error messages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I stand corrected, but I don't believe columns (or cells, rather) in JTable have any notion of datatypes. You're best to check for the expected integer and throw an exception otherwise. Eg:

```
try{
  Integer.parseInt(myTableCellValue);
}catch(ParseException e){
  //Not a valid integer
}
```

Comment: wrong - it's the responsibility of TableModel to return a per-column class assignable to all values in that column. If you need to guard against a cast failure, something is wrong with the model