# How to add checkbox in particular row in jtable in java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I have a `JTable` which has 5 rows and 8 columns. I want to add checkboxes only in the last row. So i tried an example from [How to add checkboxes to JTABLE swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391877/how-to-add-checkboxes-to-jtable-swing)h. In that example I am seeing checkbox adding for column only...But how to add checkboxes in the last row of all cells?

Answer (score 2):

- [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) (and similair GUI, MsExcell, Databases) is based on Column direction
- [in mentioned example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392163/714968) is strictly defined [ColumnClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for [XxxTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), remove these code line
- is possible to create and defined `ColumnClass` for concrete cell (every cells in the last row), but required proper definitions in XxxTableModel
- maybe easiest of ways is to use [Render](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer),
- your question isn't specific for detailed answer, sure maybe there are another options

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7137786/230513) on header controls.

Answer (score 2):

JTable has two methods of interest: `getCellRenderer(int, int)` and `getCellEditor(int, int)`. By overriding both you can provide specific renderer/editor components based on the row and column that is being rendered/edited. You might need a creative TableModel though - the swing JTable wasn't intended to handle different types of items depending on row.