# how to use DefaultCellEditor to make column of the JTable to get only numbers and round them with two signs after dot?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, decimalformat

I am not sure if this is the right way to do this but I think so. I have tried to use DecimalFormat but I cant understand it. Can someone help me? Is this the correct way to do this DefaultCellEditor + DecimalFormat?

Comment: Talk more about write way. Is this a read way for me?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, you edited and let "write way" stay there!?

Comment: @user1761818, you should put here what you tried.

Comment: @HericDenis 1) I did not edit (or carefully read) the body, just the tags. 2) When I do, it is mostly the 'red squiggly underlines' that FF thinks are wrongly spelled, that draws my eye to them.  So even if I had edited the body, it is unlikely I would have noticed the difference between 'write' and 'right'.  ;)

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) in particular [Using an Editor to Validate User-Entered Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#validtext)

Comment: That's ok @AndrewThompson, I was just annoying you bro (:

Answer (score 4):

- override [column class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392163/714968) by using `Double.Class`
- for `XxxTableCellEditor` to use `JFormattedTextField` or `JSpinner` as Editor, formatted by proper methods from `NumberFormat` or `DecimalNumberFormat`, including rounding
- set `DefaultTableCellRenderer` for desired colum
- you can to set (too) proper `Rounding method` from `NumberFormat`

for example

```
TableColumnModel tcmAmount = myTable.getColumnModel();    
TableColumn tcAmount = tcmAmount.getColumn(2);
tcAmount.setCellRenderer(new DRManMmAmount(1)); // decimal precision
```

and

```
   private static class DRManMmAmount extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        int precision = 0;
        Number numberValue;
        NumberFormat nf;

        public DRManMmAmount(int p_precision) {
            super();
            setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            precision = p_precision;
            nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
            nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(p_precision);
            nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(p_precision);
            //nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            //nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(Object value) {
            if ((value != null) && (value instanceof Number)) {
                numberValue = (Number) value;
                value = nf.format(numberValue.doubleValue()); 
            }
            super.setValue(value);
        }
    }
```